# My favorites are backed up in icon.ico format

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

Recently, my laptop updated Windows 10 and in the process updated Edge as well.  My new browser does not have any of my favorites.  I found them in my C drive in a folder named a folder named Favorites.  Each favorite is in icon.ico format.  I cant import them into Edge like this.  Does anyone know if I can convert these files into a format where I can import them?

Comment: icon.ico is just what it would appear to be… an icon. It will contain no other information.

Comment: If you are talking about Edge Chromium replacing Edge (EdgeHTML) you can enable the legacy Edge and export your favorites.  Have you tried doing that?  Edge Chromium is not suppose to replace the Legacy Edge unless you specifically install Edge Chromium.  By the way `icon.ico` files do not contain any information that can be used to import your favorites.

Comment: Why are they just icons?  It appears though these are my favorites but why not in a format where I can carry them over.  By the way, it was during a routine update that Chromium was installed and Legacy Edge was apparently uninstalled.  When I go to uninstall Chromium it wont let me.  The 'uninstall' button isn't highlighted.  Is there a way I can enable legacy Edge without uninstalling Chromium and if so, how?  Or is there a place I can find my favorites in a format that are usable for me?  Thanks.

Comment: I regret to tell you that your favourites are probably *not* backed up at all. `.ico` files are just pictures/icons. The "Favourites" folder you found may not be the *complete* data for your favourites, just a place to store the *icons for your favourites*. If you have any luck of finding the favourites still left over from the old browser, it may be somewhere in your "AppData" folder.

Comment: Your favorites should be in: C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\DataStore\Data\nouser1\120712-0049\DBStore\spartan.edb (or similar) Unfortunately this is a database file and accessing the contents is not a simple task.

Comment: I found this file but how do I access the contents?  Any help would be appreciated.  I have years of favorites here.